# List erase range from end to end

Tags: c++, list, c++11

Is it safe to call 2 arguments version of `std::list::erase` passing the list's end as both parameters?

```
std::list<int> values;
values.push_back(4);
values.erase(values.end(), values.end());
```

Of course the behaviour I expect from `values.erase(values.end(), values.end());` is doing nothing, however I'm not sure if C++11 specification assures that.

Comment: [*The iterator first does not need to be dereferenceable if first==last: erasing an empty range is a no-op.*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe to pass an empty range to [std::list::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase).

> Removes the elements in the range [first; last).
>
> The iterator `first` does not need to be dereferenceable if `first==last`: erasing an empty range is a no-op.